# Cylinder head and block replacemnt

Tags: cylinder-head, fiat, block, ducato

Wonder if you could help. I have a 1988 fiat ducato highwayman.

My motorhome was taken into an expert engine services garage.

The original problem was cylinder head gasket. The garage removed the head and sent it off to be skimmed,

They next rang ne after putting it all back together to advise the block needs replacing so I gave the go-ahead along with a full new clutch. When I eventually collected the vehicle I drove it to the off road storage where until covid restrictions had been lifted.

I drove to get a new exhaust and battery where 2nd gear only makes a crunching noise and when upto 50-55 the vehicle shudders so I rang the garage and to my amasment he more or less condemned the gearbox.

There were no gearbox issues or shuddering prior to the motohome going into the garage.

As they rang me to advise having the clutch fitted while the gearbox was out I assumed not only would the gearbox rubber mounts but the engine mounts would have been replaced being an old vehicle and as they are cheap when the engine/gearbox had been totally removed.

Hes trying to say, he only has my word that there wasn't a problem before they worked on it and older vehicles can develop issues! It hasn't moved because of covid I explained.

I've spoken to two mechanics who said it should be covered under warranty period, they checked the registration on their system and told me the gearbox rubber was worn and an advisory so the garage should of replaced it on visual inspection. They also went on to say major engine/gearbox when they have been removed the mounts/ rubbers should have been aumatically done. It's cost me 2k to have all the work done and he was well aware I had a holiday booked for my wife who had kidney failure and alot of equipment has been arranged to be delivered to holiday places so she can have dialysis on the 17th May onwards. They won't look at it until the 12th May. Any advice would be appreciated and I'm distraught as is my wife. Should the garage of replaced the mounts while the engine and gear box was out and is the garage responsible to to put the issue of second gear right ?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: My gut feel is that when they had the gearbox out, they should have noticed the transmission and engine mounts were worn.  At that time, they should have stopped all work, notified you that these mounts were worn, and would have to be replaced. And those parts are not easy to come by.  At that time they should have given you a labor and parts estimate for the extras.   You would have paid the extra funds and the repair would have been made. What we don't know is what you agreed to before the first repair was done.  When you pre-inspected the mounts yourself did you notice that they were worn?

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. When I booked it in, I said when the engine and block comes off can you check and if anything needs doing then ring me with the price and parts. On the Mot it says gearbox mount worn change as soon as possible. What gets me is why would they ring and ask about a new clutch when the one in was working perfect but not ask about mounts. Rather strange don't you think ? Clutch and gearbox was working fine before it went into them.